# Reassociate Windows 10 system hotkey

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

Windows 10 has taken <kbd>WINKEY</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and made it bring up the Feedback application.  <kbd>WINKEY</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> used to be the Windows file search in Windows, and I still catch myself hitting it sometimes on accident to find a file.

So, is it possible to disassociate a system hotkey from the system app it's tied to, and instead use it for something like 'Everything' (the third-party file index/search app)? And if so, how would I go about doing that?

'Everything' does support global hotkeys, so I don't think that'll be a problem once I can disassociate it from the Feedback app (if that's even possible).

Update:

Per Ramhound's suggestion I removed the Feedback app (didn't try before, just assumed I couldn't like most of MS's preinstalled apps).  Now <kbd>WINKEY</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> does nothing, but also seems to never get seen by Everything.  It does register <kbd>WINKEY</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>(hyphen) so I know it should work with the Windows Key.  I'm thinking Windows has that reserved and just swallows it up...

Comment: You can remove the application.  Have you tried that?

Comment: D'oh, no i havent.  Assumed it was like every other pre-installed MS app.  Trying that now...

Comment: Ok just tried it and it does seem to NOT open the feedback app anymore (obviously cuz it's gone), but the key strokes don't seem to make it to Everything either.  I will check if AutoHotKey detects it and maybe could forward it or automate Everything to pop up.  I'm thinking Windows just swallows that up though...  Everything does detect WINKEY-(hyphen) so it should work with WINKEY shortcuts

Comment: With it removed you can now use AutoHotkey to create a new shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments from @Ramhound I was able to get this working.

Uninstalling the Feedback app is possible, but it doesn't allow Everything to detect the <kbd>WINKEY</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> combination still for some reason.

However, I mapped <kbd>WINKEY</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> using the following AutoHotKey script:

```
#f::Send ^!f
```

Then in Everything, I set it to pop up when it detects the CTRL+ALT+F combination.  It now seems to work quite well.

[image]

I haven't tested this AHK approach while having the Windows 10 Feedback app installed, so I'm uncertain if uninstalling it is necessary to make this work (but that's what I did).  Now when I hit <kbd>WINKEY</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> it works to bring up "Everything"